# Open File Dialog Disappers when the parent window is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a wpf application and in that i am using file open dialog and i am facing a small problem. The problem is when i am at the file open dialog and if i click the parent window then the file dialog disappers. I dont want this to happen.
I am using a helper class for the file open dialog and here is the code for it

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MOAA.Infrastructure.Helpers
{
    public static class DialogHelper
    {
        public static string ImportFileDialog(string fileNameWithPath)
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
            {
                FileName = fileNameWithPath ?? string.Empty,
                InitialDirectory = fileNameWithPath != null ?
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNameWithPath) : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
            };
            var dialogStatus = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (dialogStatus == true)
            {
                return dialog.FileName;
           }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call that method?

Comment: var userSelectedImportFile = DialogHelper.ImportFileDialog(autoDetectedFileName);   where autodetected is the path of the file

Comment: And where is that method called from? A `Task` for example?

Comment: This is not supposed to happen, you'd normally get a loud BEEP when you click another window.   My crystal ball says that you are calling this code from another thread.  Don't do that.

Comment: Nope i am not using threads on this window but only in the initial one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the parent window when you call [ShowDialog()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh356461%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
var dialogStatus = dialog.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow);
```

Comment: I suggest passing the owner Form in, rather than using System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.  Of course, if you don't have that reference, then @HansPassant is correct.

Comment: When i try to do this i get an error asking me to reference assembly windowbase.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

You are using window dialog, so you might do some more works by wrapping it into a WPF view or window. Then, set owner for WPF control

```
 wpfDialog.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

This is how can you wrap it:

http://manfredlange.blogspot.com/2009/04/openfiledialog-in-net-on-vista.html

Hope it works.

Comment: I cannot set this property. Before posting this question itself tried it.